Can LaTeXML cooperate with package 'glossaries'?
My MWE is below:
(I have downloaded and modified LaTeXML-master, and I run ./makemanual in its doc subdirectory.) When generating .PDF, it says
No file manual.gls

and really, there is no such file. When generating .HTML, it says
Error:undefined:\DeclareRelease

and
Error:undefined:\DeclareCurrentRelease

When I uncomment
%\usepackage{latexmlman},

I receive
! LaTeX Error: Command \pod already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.905 ...f@display\mkern18mu\else\mkern8mu\fi(#1)}

I (guess I) understand that LaTeXML defines all the three; but can it cooperate with package glossaries? (I do not receive glossary and it does not compile if package latexmlman is used)
The MWE
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{latexml}
%\usepackage{latexmlman}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\begin{document}\label{top}
The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language. 

\printglossaries
\end{document}

I downloaded 0.8.8-master, removed pod-related stuff
(as they are missing).
After that, either I receive
the error
Command \pod already defined.
when I include
\usepackage{glossaries}
or error
! Undefined control sequence.
l.66 \newglossaryentry
{latex}
if do not include it.
I have downloaded LaTeXML-0.8.8, master .tgz.
It does not include '\pods' stuff,
(I do not know if it is by intention)
so I had to remove the corresponding stuff.
Sorry for the wrong wording:
only from my particular point of view,
the \pod is really defined there,
and so is \DeclareRelease and \DeclareRelease.
So, it looks like it is not a good idea to reproduce your manual. Any better approach to use all your macros, except the ones referring to the missing files?

Can you provide an minimal example?  I'm not having any errors (although recent TeXLives have the penalty associated with expl3).

I still don't understand.  Your MWE works just fine and you don't need latexmlman.  You need latexmlman to make the manual, but ./makemanual works just fine for me (and doesn't have a glossary).  Which of those are you trying to do?

I need latexmlman (it is an MWE, demonstrating the issue, not a real document), and to cooperate with glossaries.

@Teepeemm It is exacly the case: ./makemanual (with the original texts) works fine, but does not have a glossary, and I guess that is why it can work fine. I simply want to borrow the style, etc. files. And I need a glossary, in addition.

I thought I'd gotten those errors, but now I don't, and your example compiles fine even with glossaries (if pdflatex doesn't find the gls file, you might need to run the indexing or glossary command separately, or have latexmk do it).  \Declare[Current]Release should be defined in lib/LaTeXML/Engine/LaTeX.pool.ltxml.  Is your distribution up to date?

I am afraid the release information gets defined only for the manual, and I 1/ cannot find some files related to pods are missing from the distribution 2./ those definitions are defined for the manual 3./ yes I need to run glossary manually 4./ I think I have nothing to to with releases

4/ Somehow adding glossary-related stuff invokes releases stuff. Is it needed?

Another trial: as downloaded, it does not compile, it misses 'pods/' stuff, buf  that it gives the error message 'Can't locate Pod/LaTeX.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Pod::LaTeX module)' . Something is missing from my local machine  that is present on you developen machine.
